# How can I determine the potential intersection point of two gaussian time series predictions?

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution, confidence-interval, gaussian-process, prediction-interval

Sorry if some of my terminology is off, I hope I can make the problem clear.

I have two (independent) time series on the same plane, one trending slightly upwards and one slightly downwards, towards each other. At some point t=x, I use a Gaussian process to predict the future trajectory of both these time series, giving a prediction and a confidence interval over that prediction. I am trying to determine at what point these time series will meet (as in, take the same value), and with what probability.

I imagine at any point in time after the prediction there is a bivariate normal distribution over the time series, whose product gives the probability of them meeting at that point, if at all. This however only gives the probability for that 'time-slice', and I am not sure how this influences the future probabilities for them meeting at different points at a later time.

It must be noted I am more interested in the exact value at which they will meet, the time is secondary.

If someone could point me in the right direction with some resources this is also appreciated! Thanks in advance